# Javascript - Object that relies on other objects

Tags: javascript, object

```
var config = {
  xxx : 'foo'
}

var env = {
 foo : {

 },
 bar : {

}
}
```

How can I use an objects value to retrieve values from another object?

like:

```
env.config.xxx?
```

Comment: Careful about semicolons and that comma in `config`. http://goo.gl/JYnzc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var object1 = { value : 'hello' }
var object2 = { o : object1 }

alert(object2.o.value);
```

​